# Volley Error : No address associated with hostname ( wrong hostname ) [ Checked a lot on Stackoverflow]

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

I had a fully functional app, properly working and had not issue. Today, I sent that app to one of my client as a demo app and client sent screenshot that app is not working and he had tried opening app on multiple device and getting same error but the strange thing is that the same app is  working properly on all of my device without any issue.

> Error : "com.android.volley.NOConnectionError :
> java.net.UnknownHostException/; Unable to resolve host "urlpath" : No
> address associated with host name"

One thing that in Error it's not including the host name like eample.com but including the further path I used like I used https://example.com/urlpath, so it's showing "urlpath".

Here's the thing  I had already Cross checked with the client:

1. He is not using any VPN.
2. Tried both with Mobile Data and WiFi Connection.
3. Tried to open app in multiple device.
4. Device not on airplane mode.
5. Direct url on browser is opening in his device.
6. My Website is SSL secured and even then I had enabled http traffic in app.

As I error does not came in any of my device I can't have any logs of error. Help me With the Problem and Let me know if any further information is required.

Comment: Unable to resolve host should be the DNS name, not the path. Maybe you somehow dynamically construct the URL with configuration that doesn't work on their phone? Check you correctly set the protocol as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is internet error, did u give internet permission to ur app?

Comment: Yes I have Internet Permisson. As i said that App is perfectly working in my devices. but not in any of my client's device.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your app Android P and above. Do the following changes in your app

Add this to the manifest.xml:

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

create @xml/network_security_config.xml - File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

Comment: I don;t know what's the problem but changing the hosting of API resolved the problem